# Updating an entry to an SQL table - using update gives table doesn't exist error

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-update

This is my query code :

```
UPDATE `firstTable`
SET major = 'Physics' 
WHERE student_id = 2;
```

This is the error i get :

> Table 'velinsfirst.firsttable' doesn't exist

Comment: The error seems quite clear.  What do you *intend*?  Why are you ptting a date in the `UPDATE` clause?

Comment: Is this an attempt at a multi-table update? If so JAN 28 is an invalid identifier and should be backticked if it is a table name,

Comment: What does `UPDATE Jan 28, 2021` mean ?

Comment: No sorry I want to update a single cell , the name of the table is "firstTable, Jan28, 2021" and I want to add the value "physics" to the cell in row where student_id = 2.

Comment: You have to put table name in backticks, thanks P.Salmon.

Comment: Not quotes - backticks..and that's a poor table name - a better naming convention is to use underbars _ to link multipart table names and not to use white spaces.

Comment: Ok thank you for the answers, I will take your advice on the naming convention too.

Comment: Now I have a table doesn't exist error, but when I run a SELECT query the table with the data shows up. I thought this might be a problem with the name so I simplified the name as much as possible but still the same error.

Comment: Can you please update the question and add the table definition and change the statement with the simplified table name.

Comment: Done some of those, and sorry what do you mean by table definition?

Comment: Ohhhhh, sorry I'm an idiot, I realised the 'title' I have for the table is different to the name I set when I wrote the query CREATE TABLE. Ok that's sorted now

Comment: Thank you all for the input, I didn't know about he backticks so much appreciated.

Comment: Table definition you get by the command `SHOW CREATE TABLE firstTable`. For more details see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-create-table.html